# MongoDB ignore <query> on upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to upsert a document into MongoDB using the main Node driver. I want to query by `_id`, and if that `_id` doesn't exist, then create a new document with a normal ObjectId. However, from the MongoDB docs:

> The update creates a base document from the equality clauses in the `query` parameter, and then applies the update expressions from the `update` parameter.

(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior)

Meaning that it will try to use whatever I compared the `_id` to in the query section as the document's new id. The problem is that, if the document doesn't exist yet, I'm comparing `_id` to `null`, so when it creates the new document, it sets the `_id` as `null`. Is there a way to avoid this behavior? I want to query by `_id`, but not use whatever I compare it to in the upsert. Here's my code so far:

```
dbm.collection('orders').findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: order._id
        },
        {
            $set: order,
            $setOnInsert: {_id: ObjectId()}//tried with and without this
        },
        {
            upsert: true,
            returnOriginal: false
        }).then().catch()
```

Here, `order`, is an object with a few fields. And for my purposes, I need to query by _id, not some other indexed field.

Comment: As you have already noted that is not possible. Obviously, you can do null check if id is null then do insert else upsert

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing now, was just wondering if there was a more elegant method using the mongo API itself